# Constants set to Double wont return double

Tags: java

I cant seem to get this set of code to return a double for the answer on CubicCent. I know that the exact answer for 1 Gallon to Cubic Centimeter should be 3785.41178, but it keeps returning with no decimals and my grams function is only returning a single decimal. Thanks in advance.

```
public class Volume {
public static final double Liters_Per_Gallon = 3.785;
public static final double Cubic_Cent_Per_Liter = 1000.0;
public static final double Ounces_Per_Pound = 16.0;
public static final double Grams_Per_Ounce = 28.35;
private double pounds;
private double gallons;
double grams;
double CubicCent;

/**
 * @return the gallons
 */
public double getGallons() {
    return gallons;
}

/**
 * @param gallons
 *            the gallons to set
 */
public void setGallons(double gallons) {
    this.gallons = gallons;
}

/**
 * @return the pounds
 */
public double getPounds() {
    return pounds;
}

/**
 * @param pounds
 *            the pounds to set
 */
public void setPounds(double pounds) {
    this.pounds = pounds;
}

public double getCubicCent() {
    double liters = gallons * Liters_Per_Gallon;
    CubicCent = liters * Cubic_Cent_Per_Liter;
    return CubicCent;
}
public double getGrams() {
    double ounces = pounds * Ounces_Per_Pound;
    grams = ounces * Grams_Per_Ounce;
    return grams;
}
```

Comment: The issue is likely to be in how you are printing the result - decimal places are meaningless for double, because it is a binary floating point type. Please strip down the class to what is needed to reproduce the problem and add the code that makes you think you are getting one decimal place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the answer you want, you need to be more accurate in your `Liters_Per_Gallon` initialization. For example, using

```
public static final double Liters_Per_Gallon = 3.785411784;
```

gives 3785.411784 as the result. You are going to get, to the limits of double accuracy, 1000 times the constant value.

Comment: Awesome, thanks Patricia that fixed it perfectly. I understand now, it was only giving back the result in the same accuracy as the numbers it is doing the calculations on.